# Xamarin.Forms Pages are merging together

Tags: xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

When I navigate to a new page, adding it to the stack, if it is not full height of the page, it shows part of that page and part of the previous page (like a modal). I have a Xamarin.Forms app which uses a master detail page. I have upgraded to Xamarin.Forms Nuget 2.3.3.168 and am on the latest Xamarin version for Visual Studio.

I also checked the Navigation stack when going to a new page and everything looks correct. I have 1 master page which is the menu and the detail page has a navigation page with more pages in the stack, they just display partially on top of each other.

The only other thing I have changed is when I needed to initialize my `App()` constructor by setting the `MainPage` to a new `MasterDetail` page because it was failing if I did not do that in the constructor for Android. Any ideas?

Here is my App.cs:

```
   public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var masterDetailPage = new MasterDetailPage
            {
                Master = new Page() { Title = "Title" },
                Detail = new Page(),
                IsPresented = false
            };

            App.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
        }
```

Then, when I figure out if the user is logged in or not, I reset the master detail page with this function:

```
  public static void SetMainPage(Page newPage)
        {
            var rootPage = new NavigationPage(newPage) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.White};

            _nav.Initialize(rootPage);
            _dialogService.Initialize(rootPage);

            App.Current.MainPage = new MasterDetailPage
            {
               Master = new Menu(),
                Detail = rootPage,
                BindingContext = new MowMagicMobileViewModelBase(),
                IsPresented = false
            };
        }
```

Then from there I call Navigation `PushAsync()` to pop a page onto the stack.

Comment: I dont get your question? Can you add the code with problem?

Comment: @Mr.Kocak added the code

Comment: do you set the page background color to `Color.Transparent`?

Comment: This might have been a result of a recent bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=48158. It's fixed in 2.3.3 sr1. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow it was actually that I just did not set a background color at all.  I guess if you do not explicitly set it for the page it is transparent, unless that gets inherited from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if its the solution but i have masterdetail page too.. 
But my page is like this

```
Master = new MenuPage();// it is a content page 
Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
```

try it to see

If you want to change background i did sth like that

```
public class NavigationPageBase:NavigationPage
{
    public NavigationPageBase (ContentPage c):base(c)
        {
            /*if (c.GetType().Equals(typeof(LoginPage)))
                SetHasNavigationBar(c, false);
            else
                SetHasNavigationBar(c, true);*/
            SetHasNavigationBar(c, true);
            BarBackgroundColor = Styles.toolbarColor;
            BackgroundColor = Styles.bgPageColor;
        }
}
```

and for detailpage you can use it for example like

```
Detail = new NavigationPageBase (new HomePage ());
```

And from your `App()` constructor you can do simply

```
MainPage = new MyMasterDetailPage();
```

Hope it helps